# php create objects from list of class files

Tags: php, class, object, auto-generate

I have directory CLASSES with files in my project.

```
../classes/class.system.php
../classes/class.database.php
...
```

I pull out every class and include it to main index.php with this code:

```
// load classes
foreach (glob("classes/class.*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
}
```

and then I create (manually write) objects for example:

```
$system = new System();
$database = new Database();
...
```

Q: How can I automatically generate object for each class from list of files in directory CLASSES without writing them?

Thank you for your answers and code.

### EDIT:

**My working solution**:

```
// load classes
foreach (glob("classes/class.*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
    $t = explode(".",$filename);
    $obj = strtolower($t[1]);
    $class = ucfirst($t[1]);
    ${$obj} = new $class();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// load classes and create objects
foreach (glob("classes/class.*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
    $t = explode(".",$filename);
    $obj = strtolower($t[1]);
    $class = ucfirst($t[1]);
    // create object for every class
    ${$obj} = new $class();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IF you follow a typical pattern, while creating those files like

> `class.<classname>.php`

Then

```
foreach (glob("classes/class.*.php") as $filename) {
    require_once $filename;
    $t = explode(".",$filename);
    ${strtolower($t[1])}= new ucfirst($t[1])(); // automatically create the object        

}
```

Comment: I need generate $system = new System(); inside php page, so this will not work. Variable $obj is not defined and class must have first letter uppercase and class have "()" after name.

Comment: I think after class are missing "();" and better solution is using ucfirst() function

Comment: @ing.MichalHudak, Yes I missed the brackets..., and correct about the ucfirst() also

Answer (score 0):

I don't think loading all classes with `glob` and including them if you need or not is efficient or good idea performance wise. What if you have `500 different classes ???`

Why don't you take advantage of `PHP` auto loading see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php which would only load the class you need

Example

```
function __autoload($className) {
    require_once "classes/class." . $className . ".php";
}

$system = new System();
$database = new Database();
```

Comment: You’ve Got a point with glob() function. But this project have less than 20 classes. Good thing about this is I can create object automatic with loading classes in 1 while.

Comment: 20 Class for now it would definitely grow .... try i use Best Practice .... include 20 class and 1 class .. there  would definitely be a difference